# Playframework-2.0 NettyDispatcher 500 Error on Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, netty

I started getting 500 Internal Server Error(ISE) on Heroku, tried enabling debug level logs. The error is not consistent, it occurs for some request, for others it goes thru properly. When there is an ISE there is not even a single log line(even with debug on) in web dynos... I am able to see that the 500 response is given for the request.

From the client side am seeing the following

> This exception has been logged with id  **6gimbegj7**

The above line tells that it should a response from Play! when it is running in production mode.

Attached New Relic monitoring plugin where it says the Exception occurred on NettyDispatcher (Netty IO server), not further info.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

We have identified the problem here, 
In play! we have a Global.java on the root of the packages, which has the methods like

> onRequest(), onRequestRoute()

If there is any error at this place, and if we do not handle the exceptions, then Netty directly throws an 500 response to the request. This can happen from any part of the application. We did catch the exceptions in other part of the application but missed this one.

Mimicking the heoku env with the help of Foreman tool helped us to narrow down on the cause. As such setting the playframework log level to DEBUG did not throw any logs/stacktrace, Not sure why.